# Angular fails to bind expression

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-resource

I am trying to build a simple web app that communicates with an external API , for the first step i wish to check if my controller,service-html integration is all in placed , so I'm tying to bind a simple variable from the controller to the view, but i am getting **{{msg}}** instead of a successful bind.

please ignore the service for now its just my fundumentals for later on.

**main.html :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html >
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="controller.js"></script>

<head></head>
<body  ng-app="queueApi" ng-controller="MainController">
    <div>
        <h1>{{msg}}</h1>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**queueservice.js**

```
angular.module('queueApi')
.factory('queueService', function ($resource){
    return $resource('http://127.0.0.1:8080/queue/:id',{id: '@id'});

});
```

**controller.js**

```
var app = angular.module('queueApi' , ['ngResource']);
app.controller('MainController', function($scope,$http, queueService){

    $scope.msg = "Hi tom";
    // $scope.items = queueService.query({id:2}); //getting all from id 2

});
```

Comment: Your error seems related to dependencies, click F12 and open the developer tool and see the main error. For now change ['ngResource'] to [] and try again

Answer (score 2):

If you look at your console you can see the error in module creation. It is because the `ngResource` module is in external source file rather than `angular.min.js`. Add also the `angular-resource.js`.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-resource.min.js"></script>    
<script src="controller.js"></script>
```

Comment: hi Hamlet , what IDE did you use to check console?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Hamlet Hakobyan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38957562/999248) answer, you must ensure that your modules have been included in correct order. With your code structure **controller.js** should precede **queueservice.js**.

From the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module):

**Beware that using angular.module('myModule', []) will create the module myModule and overwrite any existing module named myModule. Use angular.module('myModule') to retrieve an existing module.**